# serialized object return null Java

Tags: java, serialization

I'm learning Java and running some problems to restore a serialized data in an object. I wrote this code try just as practice to apply to another project but object data is returning as null.

an example of output:
Serialized data is saved in item.ser
File Exist!!!
Deserialized item...
item@7ef20235
Sku: 0
Name: null
Price: 0.0
Is taxed: null
Quantity: 0

```
import java.io.*;
public class demo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        item i = new item("1234", "Guarana", 0.94, true, 1);


        try {



            FileOutputStream fileOut =
                    new FileOutputStream("item.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(i);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Serialized data is saved in item.ser");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
        File F = new File("item.ser");
        if (F.exists() && !F.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("File Exist!!!");
        }
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("item.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            item restore= (item) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
            System.out.println("Deserialized item...");
            System.out.println(restore);
            System.out.println("Sku: "+restore.Sku);
            System.out.println("Name: "+ restore.getName());
            System.out.println("Price: "+restore.Price);
       /* if(ret.tax.toString()=="true"){
            System.out.println("Item is taxed");

        }else{
            System.out.println("Item is not taxed");
        }*/
            System.out.println("Is taxed: "+restore.tax);
            System.out.println("Quantity: "+restore.qty);
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("Employee class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }





    }

}

//class item

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by diogowatson on 26/07/17.
 */
public class item implements Serializable{

    String PorN;
    int Sku;
    String Name;
    double Price;
    Boolean tax;
    int qty;

    public item(String s, String apple, double v, boolean b, int i) {
    }

    public void item(){}
    public void item ( String p, int s, String n, double pr, boolean t, int q){
        PorN=p;
        Sku=s;
        Name=n;
        Price=pr;
        tax=t;
        qty=q;
    }
public int getSku(){
        return Sku;
}
    public String getName(){
        return Name;
}

    public void PrinItem(){
        System.out.println("Sku: "+ Sku);
        System.out.println("name: "+ Name);
        System.out.println("Price: "+Price);
        System.out.println("Is taxed: "+ tax);
        System.out.println("Quantity: "+qty);
    }
}
```

Comment: coding is not clean. class name and method name is same. should have capital letter first in a `class` name. and your constructor doesn't pass anything on the fields of the object. that's why you get null.

Comment: `item@7ef20235 Sku: 0 Name: null Price: 0.0 Is taxed: null Quantity: 0` is not null. It is an object of type `item` whose *content* is empty.

Answer (score 2):

That is fairly simple and the problem has nothing to do with the serialization itself. You create your object with

```
item i = new item("1234", "Guarana", 0.94, true, 1);
```

which calls the **constructor** of your `item` class. That is this method of yours:

```
public item(String s, String apple, double v, boolean b, int i) {

}
```

As you see, it does not set anything. The arguments do not get passed to its internal fields thus the whole `item` object is *empty*. Try the following and you directly see what I mean:

```
item i = new item("1234", "Guarana", 0.94, true, 1);
System.out.println(i.Name) // prints null
```

---

However you are probably a bit confused as you declared the following:

```
public void item ( String p, int s, String n, double pr, boolean t, int q){
    ...
}
```

And there you actually set everything correctly. **But** this is a **method** and not the **constructor** of your `item` class (you would call such a method by `i.item(...)` for example where `i` was set by `item i = new item(...)`).

---

And that is the exact reason why the **naming conventions** suggest to begin class names with a upper case letter and method names with a lower case letter (also variable/field names should begin with a lower case letter), so usually you would call it:

```
// Class
public class Item {
    // Field
    String name;

    // Constructor
    public Item(...) {
        ...
    }

    // Method
    public void item(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

So the only thing you need to do to fix the problem is **moving the content** of your method **into the constructor**.

Comment: A lesson for the OP: Always start simple when debugging. In this case, before you investigated why your object didn't serialize correctly, you should have confirmed that it was constructed correctly in the first case. Otherwise it's like trying to build a house without being sure whether you're building in quicksand.

Comment: Thank's a lot Zabuza!! You gave me a clear, concise answer and also gave me hints on how to improve my code. It was a foolish mistake, but sometimes we need someone else to look at our code and show something obvious.

Comment: You're welcome :) If your problem was solved than please also consider **accepting** one of the answers. That helps SO to filter your question out from the unanswered questions.